# Finite groups with a dihedral maximal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with a dihedral maximal subgroup. Suppose that $G$ is not isomorphic to $\operatorname{PSL}(2,q)$ for some any prime-power $q$. Is $G$ always solvable?

Comment: $G$ could also be ${\rm PGL}(2,q)$ (as well as the Suzuki groups mentioned by Geoff Robinson).

Comment: @Derek Holt Thanks for reminding me of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not necessarily . The Suzuki simple groups ${ \rm Sz}(2^{2n+1})$ also have dihedral maximal subgroups. These are the normalizers of the Hall subgroup of order $2^{2n+1}-1.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: One could ask whether these are the only other examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I think this is a difficult question for simple groups. For example, Graham Higman proved that a finite simple group with a maximal subgroup dihedral of order $10$ has to be isomorphic to $A_{5}$, but even that makes use of the fact that Suzuki groups are the only non-Abelian simple groups of order prime to $3$.

Comment: Nowadays, it may be known which simple groups $G$ have a cyclic TI-Hall subgroup $H$ of odd order with $[N_{G}(H):H] = 2$, and with $G$ having a single conjugacy class of involutions. I don't know an explicit exhaustive list of such groups, but there may be one.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Thanks for your comments. In fact, I was thinking of a primitive permutation group on some set with dihedral point stabilizer. I mainly made use of Gorenstein-Walter's structure theorem on finite groups with dihedral Sylow 2-subgroups and O'Nan-Scott theorem to analyse this question. But I can't deal with the case when 8 does not divide the order of a point stabilizer.

Comment: In that case, I think that the maximal subgroup is the centralizer of an involution. If your group is simple, it is possible to show by transfer that the simple group has Sylow 2  subgroup of order 4, so Bender or Walter should enable you to finish.

Comment: I was meaning the case where the point stabilizer had order divisible by 4, since I had discovered used the other case above.

Comment: I can't access this paper -- https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/pdr004 -- but, depending on how explicit their main theorem is, it would seem like you might be able to use it to write down the primitive permutation groups with dihedral point stabilizer...